What is the correct way to modify skill rolls?
When you need to make a task more challenging for a PC, how do you decide whether you

add a Difficulty die,
downgrade a Proficiency die, or
add a Setback die?

Likewise, in a need to make a task easier, when do you

remove a Difficulty die,
upgrade an Ability die, or
add a Boost die?


If circumstances are making a task easier or harder than it otherwise would be, that's what Boost and Setback dice are for.

Proficiency dice represent the combination of innate skill and training. They are most often used when your character attempts a skill check using a trained skill.
Difficulty dice represent the inherent challenge or complexity of a task your character hopes to accomplish.
Boost dice represent benefits gained through luck, chance, and advantageous actions that your character takes. They reflect your character's possession of some sort of benefit or advantage, such as having ample time to complete the task or having the right equipment.
Setback dice represent problems or minor obstacles during task resolution. Setback dice represent relatively minor conditions that impair or hinder your character, such as poor lighting, obstructive terrain, or insufficient resources. [...] Add them to represent additional circumstances and environmental effects that would not in and of themselves increase the base difficulty of the task.
-- "Core Mechanics: The Dice", Genesys Core Rulebook pp. 9-10, edited for presentation order

Proficiency dice are computable based on your ability and skill levels. They don't vary from situation to situation.
Difficulty dice usually reflect the base situation regardless of other circumstances - ranged weapons have a difficulty setting based on the attack range, recovery checks have a difficulty based on the proportion of your wounds, et cetera.
If you're looking at a scenario, the rules have given you a difficulty, and you think there's some reason things should be easier or harder than baseline, you should use boost and setback dice to represent that.
